# Several e-mails in contact form

Tags: php, email, contact-form

I am trying to create a contact form that can send the message to different e-mails according to what the user choose to do.

This is my code:

```
    <?php
if($_POST)
{  

   if(isset($_POST['ort1'])) { 
    $to="a@mail.com";   
    }
  else {
    $to="b@mail.com";       
    }   



    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {

        $output = json_encode(array( //create JSON data
            'type'=>'error', 
            'text' => 'Sorry Request must be Ajax POST'
        ));
        die($output); //exit script outputting json data
    } 

    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $r_name      = filter_var($_POST["r_name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $r_email     = filter_var($_POST["r_email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $ort1      = filter_var($_POST["ort1"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $ort2      = filter_var($_POST["ort2"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //additional php validation
    if(strlen($r_name)<4){ // If length is less than 4 it will output JSON error.
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Name is too short or empty!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($r_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ //email validation
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please enter a valid email!'));
        die($output);
    }

    //email body
    $message_body = $r_name."\r\nEmail : ".$r_email;

    //proceed with PHP email.
    $subject = 'From: The president' .
    $headers = 'From: '.$r_name.'' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$r_email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


    $send_mail = mail($to, $subject, $headers, $message_body);  

    if(!$send_mail)
    {
        //If mail couldn't be sent output error. Check your PHP email configuration (if it ever happens)
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
        die($output);
    }else{
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hi '.$r_name .' Thank you for your email'));
        die($output);
    }
}
?>
```

Html:

```
<div class="form-style" id="contact_form">
<div class="form-style-heading">Please Contact Us</div>
<div id="contact_results"></div>
<div id="contact_body">
    <label><span>Name <span class="required">*</span></span>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required="true" class="input-field"/>
    </label>
    <label><span>Email <span class="required">*</span></span>
        <input type="email" name="email" required="true" class="input-field"/>
    </label>
    <label>
    <span>Norr</span><input type="checkbox" name="ort1">
    <span>Söder</span><input type="checkbox" name="ort2">
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>&nbsp;</span><input type="submit" id="submit_btn" value="Submit" />
    </label>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#submit_btn").click(function() { 

    var proceed = true;
    //simple validation at client's end
    //loop through each field and we simply change border color to red for invalid fields       
    $("#contact_form input[required=true], #contact_form textarea[required=true]").each(function(){
        $(this).css('border-color',''); 
        if(!$.trim($(this).val())){ //if this field is empty 
            $(this).css('border-color','red'); //change border color to red   
            proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag
        }
        //check invalid email
        var email_reg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/; 
        if($(this).attr("type")=="email" && !email_reg.test($.trim($(this).val()))){
            $(this).css('border-color','red'); //change border color to red   
            proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag              
        }   
    });

    if(proceed) //everything looks good! proceed...
    {
        //get input field values data to be sent to server
        post_data = {
            'r_name'     : $('input[name=name]').val(), 
            'r_email'    : $('input[name=email]').val(), 
            'ort1'       : $('input[name=ort1]').val(),
            'ort2'       : $('input[name=ort2]').val()

        };

        //Ajax post data to server
        $.post('process.php', post_data, function(response){  
            if(response.type == 'error'){ //load json data from server and output message     
                output = '<div class="error">'+response.text+'</div>';
            }else{
                output = '<div class="success">'+response.text+'</div>';
                //reset values in all input fields
                $("#contact_form  input[required=true], #contact_form textarea[required=true]").val(''); 
                $("#contact_form #contact_body").slideUp(); //hide form after success
            }
            $("#contact_form #contact_results").hide().html(output).slideDown();
        }, 'json');
    }
});

//reset previously set border colors and hide all message on .keyup()
$("#contact_form  input[required=true], #contact_form textarea[required=true]").keyup(function() { 
    $(this).css('border-color',''); 
    $("#result").slideUp();
});
```

});

As you can see I did an if loop in the beginning but unfortunately it always send to a@mail.com. I have been trying to find another solution but I can't understand why this one is not working.

Comment: How does the HTML look like? Because it seems like the 'ort1' parameter is not in the form you send as POST to the server.

Comment: `if` isn't a loop.  Anyway, if `isset($_POST['ort1'])` is false then that means that `$_POST['ort1']` isn't set.

Comment: you have an answer below. If that doesn't work for you, you'll know why and "what" to do. ;-)

Comment: you're probably using a `<select>` radio/checkbox, who knows. It's pure guesswork really.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the HTML. I have updated the code.

Comment: you have no `ortX` name attribute anywhere, you have `testX`. nor do I see `<form>` tags or post method. So again, see the answer below. ask him (Edit: Oh, now you edited). Well, the answer is simple.

Comment: @Fred -ii- I forgot to change the attribute

Comment: and this could give you a false positive `if($_POST)`

Comment: then you have `["r_name"]` and `["r_email"]` with no matching attribute for those. So.. undefined index............. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: I also have jQuery but that code has nothing to do wit the problem.

Comment: I added the jQuery just so people will understand the whole code.. Sorry for that.

Comment: well if it's a JS issue, I'm not the guy for this. I suck at JS *lol*. So, check for errors and look at your console, if it's a JS issue. I can only help you with serverside code. see Matt's answer, but he's using `empty()` whereas your `isset()` is correct for the checkbox. However, your headers are wrong `$send_mail = mail($to, $subject, $headers, $message_body);` and could most likely be the (root of the) problem, and/or is playing a major role here. You need to invert the last 2 variables here `$send_mail = mail($to, $subject, $message_body, $headers);`

Comment: but you're going to face a problem here if someone clicks on both checkboxes. Is that what you also want to offer, send to 1 or 2 emails? If it's 2, well... that's an issue since you're not breaking those apart using `foreach` etc. so your best bet if you want to allow for only 1 choice, use radio buttons.

Comment: Yes I would like them to choose one not use both so radio buttons should be the way to go. Thanks! I did not understand what you meant with your comment before? How should I do?

Comment: (deleted original comment, forgot something) You're welcome. Change `type="checkbox"` to `type="radio"` for both and give them both the **same name attribute** and fix your header as I stated. I can't test this if it's a JS problem. I'll probably spend 4-5 hours trying to figure it out *lol*

Comment: I really appreciate your help, Thanks! did this now:   
    $message_body = $r_name."\r\nEmail : ".$r_email;
    
    $subject = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $subject = 'Contactform';
   
    $send_mail = mail($to, $subject, $message_body);

Comment: Also I changed to the radio buttons. Unfortunately it did not work